# How to use get_the_ID() wordpress function (or analog) to get the id of page, not of template, that page includes

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress installation with woocommerce. Every page like, for example, product category page, consists of several templates, combined together. For example, just after the header, i have "afterheader" template, where i want to show something, depending on product category id.

So, i use get_the_ID() function in this template. But it returns the **id of template**, not **id of the product category** page. Which function i can use to detect the id of whole page in the template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_queried_object_id()` function to get the ID of the currently queried object. If you're on a product category page, this function should provide the ID of the displayed category:

```
$pageId = get_queried_object_id();

if ( is_product_category() && $page_id ) {
    /* Something */
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried :   `$pageId = get_queried_object_id(); var_dump($pageId);` and i does not work - shows me "int(0)". While at the same time get_the_ID() shows me the id of template. The code is inside the template

Comment: @AlexFramuga

check if you are currently in the main query with is_main_query() and then use get_queried_object_id() function

Comment: if you still get '0', I think you should use global $post; $post->ID to get the ID of the current post/page

Comment: Yes, i checked, it use :  ` if (is_main_query()) { echo "this is main query<br>";$pageId=get_queried_object_id();var_dump($pageId); }` and i see "int(0)"

Comment: i tried `global $post; echo $post->ID;` - it shows me the id of template, not of page